# How to point a domain name to specific subdomain on Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, namecheap

I have purchased a domain name (https://example.com) from namecheap. I have a subdomain (https://subdomain.go.com:444) running on specific port on windows web server. If someone visits (https://example.com), I would like him to land on my subdomain (https://subdomain.go.com:444). How can I achieve this?

I have tried URL redirect record in DNS settings on namecheap but that did not work.

- Type : URL Redirect Record
- Host : @
- Value : https://subdomain.go.com:444

I also want the address to show as example.com instead of https://subdomain.go.com:444 in my browser(masking).

*** ref:- https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9678/2237/how-to-redirect-subdomain-to-a-certain-ip-address-along-with-a-port/

Comment: Put the output from this command in your question: **curl -v https://example.com**

Comment: I am running an API on subdomain which will resolve a (shortlink.io/raxdv). Consider shortlink.io as my example.com domain. I am not posting the output since it only displays the 200 status and html of coming soon webpage hosted on wordpress on bluehost. I just want to know the generic approach to resolve this. How can I bind my domain name to subdomain on specific port? be mindful other site is up and running on windows server domain+subdomains. Do I just need to add A record? reverse proxy can't be used since multiple sites are running on windows server.